Test loss immediately goes up on LSTM
I'm trying to create an LSTM that predicts the sixth sports match for team A based on a sequence of 5 previous matches. My data is set up in a structure like this. Team A game 1 vs random team, team B game 1 vs random team, ... Team A game 5 vs random team, team B game 5 vs random team. Team B is the team that Team A is playing in the sixth game and the result is the output. Each sequence consists of 124 features which is the combination of both team A's i'th game and team B's i'th game.
My problem is that my test loss immediately goes up, and I cant seem to be able to every have it decrease consistently. I've messed around with the hyperparameters, but none of them seem to have a noticeable effect. What can I do?
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader


def main():
    # Device
    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    print(torch.cuda.is_available())
    print(f'Running on device: {device}')

    # Process data
    data = pd.read_csv('matchup_data.csv')

    # Columns that are one-hot encoded for the label
    labels = data['label']

    # Remove the original one-hot encoded label columns from the features data
    data = data.drop('label', axis=1)

    num_features = 124
    samples = 531
    timesteps = 5

    # Convert features and labels to tensors
    dataT = torch.tensor(data.values).float()
    dataT = dataT.view(samples, timesteps, num_features)

    labelsT = torch.tensor(labels.values).float()
    labelsT = labelsT.unsqueeze(1)

    print(dataT)

    # Split to test and train data
    train_data, test_data, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(dataT, labelsT, test_size=.1)

    train_dataset = TensorDataset(train_data, train_labels)
    test_dataset = TensorDataset(test_data, test_labels)

    batch_size = 2  # Choose a batch size that fits your data and model

    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

    # Layer parameters
    input_size = 124
    hidden_size = 64
    num_layers = 2
    output_size = 1

    # Net and net parameters
    net = LSTMnet(input_size, output_size, hidden_size, num_layers).to(device)
    print(net)
    loss_function = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.00001)

    train_accuracy, train_losses, test_accuracy, test_losses = trainModel(100, net, optimizer, loss_function,
                                                                          train_loader, test_loader, device)



    print(np.max(train_accuracy))
    print(np.min(train_losses))
    print(np.max(test_accuracy))
    print(np.min(test_losses))

    # Plot accuracy and loss
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(train_accuracy, label='Train Accuracy')
    plt.plot(test_accuracy, label='Test Accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    plt.legend()

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(train_losses, label='Train Loss')
    plt.plot(test_losses, label='Test Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.legend()

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


class LSTMnet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, num_hidden, num_layers):
        super().__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size
        self.num_hidden = num_hidden
        self.num_layers = num_layers

        # RNN layer
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, num_hidden, num_layers)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.6)

        # linear layer for output
        self.out = nn.Linear(num_hidden, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Run through RNN layer
        y, hidden = self.lstm(x)

        # pass through dropout
        y = self.dropout(y)
        # Pass to linear layer
        output = self.out(y)

        return output, hidden


def trainModel(num_epochs, net, optimizer, loss_function, train_data, test_data, device):
    # Variable initialization
    train_accuracy = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    train_losses = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    test_accuracy = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    test_losses = np.zeros(num_epochs)

    for epochi in range(num_epochs):
        net.train()

        segment_loss = []
        segment_accuracy = []
        for X, y in train_data:
            X = X.to(device)
            y = y.to(device)
            output, _ = net(X)  # Unpack the tuple to get the output
            output = output[:, -1, :]
            loss = loss_function(output, y)  # Use .squeeze() to ensure the dimensions match

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # Convert output logits to probabilities using sigmoid
            probabilities = torch.sigmoid(output)
            # Convert probabilities to binary predictions
            predicted = (probabilities > 0.5).float()
            # Calculate accuracy
            acc = (predicted == y).float().mean() * 100

            segment_loss.append(loss.item())
            segment_accuracy.append(acc.item())

        train_losses[epochi] = np.mean(segment_loss)
        train_accuracy[epochi] = np.mean(segment_accuracy)

        net.eval()
        test_loss = []
        test_acc = []

        with torch.no_grad():
            for X, y in test_data:
                X = X.to(device)
                y = y.to(device)
                output, _ = net(X)  # Unpack the tuple to get the output
                output = output[:, -1, :]
                loss = loss_function(output, y)  # Use .squeeze() to ensure the dimensions match

                # Convert output logits to probabilities using sigmoid
                probabilities = torch.sigmoid(output)
                # Convert probabilities to binary predictions
                predicted = (probabilities > 0.5).float()
                # Calculate accuracy
                acc = (predicted == y).float().mean() * 100

                test_loss.append(loss.item())
                test_acc.append(acc.item())

            test_losses[epochi] = np.mean(test_loss)
            test_accuracy[epochi] = np.mean(test_acc)

    return train_accuracy, train_losses, test_accuracy, test_losses


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()




What is the orientation of your data tensor? nn.LSTM expects the input to be of shape (sl, bs, n), with the batch axis as the second axis. If your tensor is formatted (bs, sl, n), you need to pass batch_first=True to nn.LSTM

I believe its in the correct order with it having the order of (number of rows of data, number of sequences in one row, number of features for each sequence)

My understanding is that the shape of X in net(X) is (2, 5, 62 + 62), and the shape of y in loss_function(output, y) is (2, 1). The input sequence is [A vs. rand + B vs. rand (game 1), ..., A vs. rand + B vs. rand (game 5)]. The output corresponds to [A vs. B (game 6)].
If your data is arranged (seq_length, batch_size, n_features), which I think is the case as per your comment above, then I think you'll need to change the line:
#output = output[:, -1, :] #accesses last sample only
output = output[-1, :, :] #corrected - access last frame from each sample

Currently, it's reading out the last sample from each batch rather than reading out the last frame from each sample. As a result, it's optimising based on only 1 sample per batch, which might be causing the overfitting behaviour.
The correction would need to be applied in both the train and test loops.
To avoid overfitting, try decreasing n_layers to 1, and hidden_size to 16 (perhaps remove lr= from Adam to use the default). This is because the input dimensionality seems a bit large, and the number of samples might be small in relative terms. This should result in it not diverging as rapidly.
If that works, another thing you might like to try is using a Conv1d layer to 'compress' the 124-dimensional input down to something smaller. That should retain the important information whilst also reducing the dimensionality of the data, mitigating overfitting. Here's a simple way of modifying the existing code without needing to make any other changes:
#Just the LSTM
#net = LSTMnet(input_size, output_size, hidden_size, num_layers).to(device)

#Conv1d to reduce feature size from 124 down to 32, followed by an LSTM
net = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Conv1d(in_channels=124, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1),
  nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
  nn.ReLU(),

  nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1),
  nn.BatchNorm1d(32),
  nn.ReLU(),

  #Finally, the LSTM
  LSTMnet(input_size=32, output_size=output_size, num_hidden=32, num_layers=2)
).to(device)

You could start with just the the first nn.Conv1d line, and add the other lines depending on whether you think it's worth it. The input and output shapes to net don't change; it's just that internally it maps the feature down size to something smaller before feeding it to an LSTM.
About the test loss going down then up...whilst the training loss should keep going down, the test loss may well go down then up. This happens naturally and just indicates that the model is now overfitting. You'd just need to stop training before it starts overfitting (if you train for long enough you'll almost always eventually see the down-then-up test loss trend). I usually track test score (e.g. accuracy in your case), and stop training when the score hits its peak before it starts to decline, indicating overfitting.

In my answer above I'd originally used a kernel_size of 1, but that means convolutional layers aren't pulling in information from other timesteps, and therefore the data fed into the LSTM isn't as useful as it could be.
You could try increasing kernel_size, whilst at the same time setting padding='same' if you want to preserve the same sequence lengths. Playing with dilation= also allows the conv layer to see other parts of the sequence, and might be worth looking at if you have success with kernel_size.
Note that as long as you're only using the final output of the LSTM, you're okay to use Conv1d (where the kernel looks both back and ahead in time). Otherwise, I think you'd need to switch to a causal convolutional layer. This would be relevant if you switch to a sequence-to-sequence architecture (currently it's sequence-to-vector, but there can be convergence benefits to reframing it as sequence-to-vector).

I eddited my code so that batch_first = true and modified my data shape to match what the lstm is expecting where the shape is (bs, sl, n) . After doing so I kept the line output = output[:, -1, :] the same. That should correct the problem of accessing last sample only, But my test loss still shoots up.

I see. My understanding is that the shape of X in net(X) is (2, 5, 62 + 62), and the shape of y in loss_function(output, y) is (2, 1). The input sequence is [A vs. rand + B vs. rand (game 1), ...,  A vs. rand + B vs. rand (game 5)]. The output corresponds to [A vs. B (game 6)]. To avoid overfitting, try decreasing n_layers to 1, and hidden_size to 16 (perhaps remove lr= from Adam to use default). This is because the input dimensionality seems a bit large, and the number of samples might be small in relative terms. Does it diverge as rapidly when you shrink the model this way?

Ok, so something really interesting happened. I shortened the sequence to 1 for now so I would have a lot more data to work with. Right now the data is ( Team A match 1 vs some team, Team B match 1 vs some team, and Team A vs Team B as the label). My hidden_size is now 8 and my num_layers is now1 1. I left my lr as 0.00001 because its been giving me stable results. Now, training and test loss are going down very slowly, but after a certain amount of epochs, my test loss starts going up slowly. I'll keep messing with the parameters, and I'll keep you updated.

Also yes your understanding of the data is correct. The reasoning for lowering the sequence to 1 is that a lot of teams don't have at least 5 matches.

It sounds like it was a matter of overfitting (i.e. hyperparameter tuning) rather than something wrong with the program logic. Another thing you might like to try is using a Conv1d layer to 'compress' the 124-dimensional input down to something smaller. That should retain the important information whilst also reducing the dimensionality of the data, mitigating overfitting.

Hmmm, I tried doing this but I still get the phenomenon of the test loss going down and then back up. Ill keep messing with the hyperparameters to see what I get.

I guess it could be that I don't have enough data. Ill try some data augmentation techniques and see how that goes.

Yeah perhaps you'd need more data in order for a reliable pattern to be discerned. Could it be that the data is not strongly predictive? The task sounds like based on Team A & B's performance in 5 sequentially-played matches against others, does Team A beat Team B? Depending on the sport, though I'm no expert, I'd expect a predictive ability more than chance but with wide error bars (in finals of some sports, outcome can be really uncertain). If there's a record of predictions made by humans, that could indicate a baseline accuracy that the model should be able to surpass by at least a bit.

About the test loss going down then up...whilst the training loss should keep going down, the test loss may well go down then up. This happens naturally and just indicates that the model is now overfitting. You'd just need to stop training before it starts overfitting (if you train for long enough you'll almost always eventually see the down-then-up test loss trend). I usually track test score (e.g. accuracy in your case), and stop training when the score hits its peak before it starts to decline, indicating overfitting.

So I've been messing with Optuna and I'm able to get up to 78% accuracy with a smaller dataset and right now around 61% on a larger dataset. My question is now though, I'm saving the model on the epoch with the highest test accuracy. Is this valid or should I be saving it at the lowest loss?

I think you're right to be saving the model with the highest test accuracy. The test score is often the ultimate benchmark of how useful the model is. The loss is more like a mathematical tool that allows the algorithm to converge. Loss may not be directly interpretable, but the score usually is, because it's how we decide on whether the model is good for its intended purpose. About the larger dataset....making the model larger might improve on the 61%, as it sounds like it could be underfitting.

I tried to make the model bigger, but wasn't able to fix my underfitting problem. I made my LSTM a bidirecitonal one and well see how that works out for me.

I see. I noticed that I originally suggested kernel_size=1, but I think it's worth looking at larger sizes - I've updated the end of my answer with some comments on this.

Would you think it's smarter to have this as a binary classifier where each matchup is independent of the other or is it smarter to have it as a multiclass classifier? There are often times when if the data is team a vs team b, I will get a low probability of winning out of both of them.

If the outcome at each step is binary (i.e. outcome is either A or B, and never A and B), then I think using a multi-class output would be suitable as it forces the model to decide on either A or B. It's a way of incorporating your prior knowledge about the data into the model (constraining the sort of output it can produce). I think that's what you were originally doing with the BCEWithLogitsLoss.
